# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for ssrs https

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, https, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Can anyone help on out on this error?
i'm getting error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" while try to generate ssrs reports.
i'm using asp.net framework 3.5 and used SSRS report version 8 in my application, currently my ssrs report server url is **http** protocal, while applied SSL certificate in report server now report url is **https** and now tried to generate ssrs report showing **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel** Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Issue has been resolved after 2 lines of code. just add below two line code in your page load where you are trying to acces https URL. `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`